# A paper question about the security of hybrid encryption scheme

Tags: hybrid-encryption

[image: Paper screenshot]

Why the decryptor can still use K to access the data even when K is updated?
QAQ

Comment: Nevertheless, an issue will arise when the RABE scheme is implemented as a hybrid encryption scheme. That is, we use ABE to encrypt a symmetric-key K , and then encrypt the real data by a symmetric-key encryption scheme (e.g., AES) with K . Under the hybrid encryption setting, if a decryptor has previously decrypted and saved the symmetric-key K , then the decryptor can still use K to access the data even when the ABE ciphertext containing K is updated.

Comment: The Image content (Why the image is invalid ? QAQ)

Comment: merge you comments to your question , it is better

Comment: China just recently banned imgur, which is the image storage service provider of StackExchange. Would you kindly consider typing, or copypasting the text instead?

Comment: Please provide a citation for the paper that contains this screenshot, so readers can look at the paper for more context.

Comment: The screenshot is from :"Secure Fine-Grained Access Control and Data Sharing for Dynamic Groups in the Cloud" by Xu et al. in IEEE TIFS’18